# Can I avoid RTTI?

Tags: c++, rtti

```
class Number{
public:
    virtual int compare(const Number& rhs) =0;
}

class Number2 : public Number{
public:
    int compare(const Number& rhs){/* *** */ }

};

class Number3 : public Number{
public:
    int compare(const Number& rhs){ /* *** */  }


};
```

And for Example.

```
Number2 f,s;
Number& ref  = f;
ref.compare(s);
```

So, it calls Number2::compare ( reference to s is implicitly upcast)
But it is a problem because I should know type of s to make a comparison.

Can I avoid RTTI?

Comment: I don't see how you can avoid RTTI here...  Maybe if you showed us what you want to do differently depending on the type of `s`, we can find a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using double dispatch

```
class Number {
  protected:
  virtual Number& operator+(const Integer&) = 0;
  virtual Number& operator+(const Complex&) = 0;
  virtual Number& operator-(const Integer&) = 0;
  virtual Number& operator-(const Complex&) = 0;
// For all inherited types
  public:
  virtual Number& operator+(const Number&) = 0;
  virtual Number& operator-(const Number&) = 0;
};
class Integer : public Number {
  private:
  int I;
  protected:
  virtual Number& operator+(const Integer&);
  virtual Number& operator+(const Complex&);
  public:
  Integer(int x) : i(x) {}
  virtual Number& operator+(const Number&);
  // etc.
};
Number& Integer::operator+(const Number& n)
{
   return n + *this; // Replace rhs with lhs
}
Number& Integer::operator+(const Integer& n)
{
  // Here is some pseudocode
  if (i + n.i to big for int int) 
  {
    return LongInteger;
  }
  else 
    return Integer(i + n.i);
}
```

you can also google [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) topic for more info

in your case

do not forget implement comparision in reverse maner because we perform it from rhs side

```
class Number2;
class Number3;

class Number{
    public:
    virtual int compare(const Number2& rhs) const = 0;
    virtual int compare(const Number3& rhs) const = 0;
    virtual int compare(const Number& rhs)  const = 0;
};

class Number2 : public Number{
protected:
    virtual int compare(const Number2& rhs)  const  { /* your implementation */ }
    virtual int compare(const Number3& rhs)  const  { /* your implementation */ }
public:
    int compare(const Number& rhs)  const {  return rhs.compare(*this); }

};

class Number3 : public Number{
protected:
    virtual int compare(const Number2& rhs)  const { /* your implementation */ }
    virtual int compare(const Number3& rhs)  const { /* your implementation */}
public:
    int compare(const Number& rhs)  const {  return rhs.compare(*this);  }
};
```

here is some example code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

class Number2;
class Number3;

class Number{
    public:
    virtual int opposite_compare(const Number2& rhs) const = 0;
    virtual int opposite_compare(const Number3& rhs) const = 0;
    virtual int compare(const Number& rhs)  const = 0;
};

class Number2 : public Number{
protected:
    virtual int opposite_compare(const Number2& rhs)  const;
    virtual int opposite_compare(const Number3& rhs)  const;
public:
    int m_Val;
    Number2(int a) : m_Val(a) { }
    int compare(const Number& rhs)  const {  return rhs.opposite_compare(*this); }
};

class Number3 : public Number{
protected:
    virtual int opposite_compare(const Number2& rhs)  const;
    virtual int opposite_compare(const Number3& rhs)  const;
public:
    int m_Val0;
    int m_Val1;
    Number3(int a, int b) : m_Val0(a), m_Val1(b) { }
    int compare(const Number& rhs)  const {  return rhs.opposite_compare(*this);  }
};

int Number2::opposite_compare(const Number2& rhs)  const  
{ 
    return m_Val == rhs.m_Val ? 0 : (m_Val > rhs.m_Val ? -1 : 1); 
}
int Number2::opposite_compare(const Number3& rhs)  const  
{ 
    return m_Val == (rhs.m_Val0 + rhs.m_Val1) ? 0 : (m_Val > (rhs.m_Val0 + rhs.m_Val1) ? -1 : 1); 
}

int Number3::opposite_compare(const Number2& rhs)  const 
{ 
    return (m_Val0 + m_Val1) == rhs.m_Val ? 0 : ((m_Val0 + m_Val1) > rhs.m_Val ? -1 : 1); 
}

int Number3::opposite_compare(const Number3& rhs)  const 
{ 
    return (m_Val0 + m_Val1) == (rhs.m_Val0 + rhs.m_Val1) ? 0 : ((m_Val0 + m_Val1) > (rhs.m_Val0 + rhs.m_Val1) ? -1 : 1); 
}

int main(){

 Number* pOne = new Number2(9);
 Number* pTwo = new Number3(6, 3);

 std::cout << "One comp Two: " << pOne->compare(*pTwo) << std::endl;

 delete pOne;
 delete pTwo;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty complex and doesn't work. A first problem you can work on is where the result of an arithmetic operation should be stored.

Comment: What you mean? I have tested your code and it works fine.

Comment: comapre operation is stored in int result

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear what you're after, but evidently you want to represent different kinds of numbers as C++ classes, with inheritance relationships.

Then let's consider integers versus rationals. A rational number is simply one integer divided by another, a fraction, and can be specified as a pair of integers, *a*/*b*. Every integer *x* is equal to a rational, namely *x*/1.

And so, every integer **is-a** rational number. The set of rational number values, includes the set of integer values as a proper subset.

In C++ the usual way to express an is-a relationship is as class inheritance. But here it yields a silly result: that `Integer` should inherit from `Rational`, so that every `Integer` is-a `Rational`. Yet a `Rational` instance needs to hold *two* integers to represent its value, in general. With the proposed inheritance an `Integer` instance would hold an integer that would always be 1. Not to mention the circular relationship here of defining `Rational` in terms of a derived class `Integer` (of course that can be fixed by introducing `Basic_integer`, which can just be a typedef for `int`, but still).

Happily there's a way out: to not use class inheritance, but *implicit conversions*, to model the logical is-a relationships.

Then we have `Integer` as a distinct and first defined class, and `Rational` as a second defined class, with a constructor that converts an `Integer` to `Rational` (by the simple means of taking an `Integer` argument). The comparison functions defined for `Integer` work fine for `Integer`, but when you compare an `Integer` to a `Rational`, only the comparison functions for `Rational` match, and are invoked via implicit conversion of the `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the problem that you're trying to address, in particular if you really need a polymorphic hierarchy. 
But with the code snippet you provided templates would probably help. That is (for example) you declare a templated comparison helper:

```
template<typename TNumber1, typename TNumber2>
class CompareHelper;
```

Then you provide a template specialization for the different types, e.g.

```
template<>
class CompareHelper<int,double>
{
    static int compare(const int &i, const double &d)
    {
        // int to double comparision with an epsilon threshold
        return abs(i-d) < 1e-6;
    }
}
```

You can use this compare helper as:

```
int i = 2;
double d = 2 + 1e-8;
int result = CompareHelper<int,double>(i,d);
```

**Edit**
Here is a comparision for int-int that might help to understand the concept:

```
template<>
class CompareHelper<int,int>
{
    static int compare(const int &i1, const int &i2)
    {
        // int to int
        return i1 == i2;
    }
}
```

The nice thing (but probably arguable) is that it won't compile for types for which no specialization is provided.